# É possível armazenar inputs do usuário pela Classe Scanner em um banco de dados?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, scanner

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tenho uma aplicação feita em Java, e preciso armazenar no banco de dados as informações cadastrais do usuário:

cpf, senha, nome, endereco, telefone

```
System.out.println("Digite seu CPF");
cpf = ler.nextLine();           

System.out.println("Senha: ");
senha = ler.nextLine();

System.out.print("Nome Completo: ");
nome = ler.nextLine();

System.out.print("Endereço: ");
endereco = ler.nextLine();

System.out.print("Telefone: ");
telefone = ler.nextInt();
```

Quero obter esses dados através da classe Scanner e salvar no banco de dados.

Para gerenciar o banco de dados estou utilizando o PostgresSQL, e a IDE para aplicação é o Eclipse.

Já fiz a conexão do banco de dados com o Eclipse através do JDBC, porém não sei como obtenho os inputs do usuário e armazeno no Banco de Dados utilizando a Classe Scanner do Java. Eu pesquisei na internet e os únicos tutorias que encontro é usando Jframe e a IDE é o NetBeans.

```
//Conexão do eclipse com o postgresql


import java.sql.*;
public class ConexaoSQL {

    //Statement = Realizar pesquisa no banco de dados
    public Statement stm;
    //ResulSet = Armazenar o resultado da pesquisa
    public ResultSet rs;

    //Driver = identifica no serviço do banco de dados
    private String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";;

    //Caminho = Indica qual o diretório do banco de dados
    private String caminho = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/agencia";;

    /*
     Usuário: postgres
     Senha: admin
     */
    private String usuario = "postgres";;
    private String senha = "admin";;

    //Conection = Realizar a Conexão com banco de Dados
    public Connection con;

    public void conexao(){ //conecta ao banco de dados
        System.setProperty("jdbc.Drivers", driver);
        try {
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(caminho, usuario, senha);
            System.out.println("Conectado com Sucesso ao SQL!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Erro de conexão ao SQL");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void desconecta(){//desconecta do banco de dados
        try {
            con.close();
            System.out.println("Desconectado com Sucesso!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Erro ao fechar conexão com banco de dados");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar ou enviar um tutorial que tenha algo semelhante? Desde já agradeço por qualquer ajuda.

```
      Table PostGreSQL
```

Comment: O que você já fez? Adicione o codigo do seu formulario e da sua classe de conexão na pergunta.

Comment: acrescentei oq fiz no momento.

Comment: Alexandre sua aplicação é somente em modo de texto?

Comment: Sim, apenas texto, todas as informações são impressas no console.

Comment: Jovem, é a mesma coisa usando JFrame ou Scanner. Só muda de onde vem os dados.

Comment: Quais colunas tem sua tabela que quer salvar  os dados e qual o tipo das colunas?

Comment: Table: Cliente

Colum:
cpf
senha
nome
endereco
telefone

Comment: @AlexandreVieiradeSouza se toda informação a gente ter que ficar perguntando em separado ou várias vezes, vai ficar dificil te ajudar. Todas as perguntas que fiz foram bem claras, mas eu acabo tendo que perguntar de novo para você responder. Leia o que foi questionado e tente responder de forma mais completa possivel.

Comment: @diegofm Me desculpe pelo inconveniente, eu sou novo no fórum, ainda estou aprendendo a usar alguns dos recursos. Eu inseri uma imagem da tabela com as colunas na pergunta, todas as colunas foram criadas são do tipo character varying. A aplicação em java é somente no modo texto e todas as informações serão impressas no console.

Answer (score 2):

Se você ja tem todas as informações corretas nas variáveis (Se não ocorreu nenhum inconveniente usando o objeto de Scanner) então você pode salvar no banco utilizando um objeto de `PreparedStatement`

Ficaria mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
//...
ConexaoSQL conexao = new ConexaoSQL();
conexao.conexao();
Connection = conexao.con;
PreparedStatement statement = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try{
   sb.append("insert into Cliente values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
   statement = con.preparedStatement(sb.toString());
   statement.setString(1, cpf);
   statement.setString(2, senha);
   statement.setString(3, nome);
   statement.setString(4, endereco);
   statement.setString(5, telefone);
   statement.execute();
   con.commit();
}catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("Alguma exceção ocorreu" + e.toString());
}
```

É necessário você ajusta de acordo com seus requisitos.
Mas basicamente você utiliza um objeto de `PreparedStatement` para inserir esses dados na sua tabela.
Note que eu utilizei String em todos os campos, mas se o tipo de dado do seu campo for diferente, você deve ajustar de acordo com o tipo de dado do banco.

Qualquer dúvida, estou a disposição.

Comment: Uma duvida boba, porque usar Stringbuilder, ao inves de passar diretamente a query no prepareStatement?

Comment: Apenas costume. Você pode passar a query diretamente no preparedStatement sem problemas. No entanto, vai existir casos que sua query não é tão bem definida, por exemplo, você vai precisar parar a string, adicionar algo dinamicamente, e voltar a escrever a string, tipo `"insert into " + Cliente.NOME_TABELA + " values (?,?,?,?,?)";`. Para evitar utilizar esse "+", sempre utilize o StringBuilder, ele tem maior performance.

Comment: A questão de performance, já li varios debates a respeito do uso de diversas formas de concatenação de strings e a diferença é bem pequena, mas na questão de organização de código, realmente é uma boa essa forma mesmo.

Comment: A diferença é pequena sim, concordo. Mas sempre utilizo o StringBuilder. Bom, já ouvi falar por ai que o "+" chama um StringBuffer implicitamente, mas não posso afirmar isso.

Comment: obrigado @AndrewRibeiro vou tentar implementar, se conseguir eu comento ;)

Comment: Olá @AndrewRibeiro, eu implementei o que você mandou, ao rodar a aplicação ele aparece 

Alguma exceção ocorreujava.lang.NullPointerException

Todos os dados declarados no banco estão como character varying e na aplicação como String. Não entendo qual o motivo do erro.

Comment: @AlexandreVieiradeSouza, sua aplicação esta tentando usar um método de um objeto nulo. Você deve verificar qual linha esta o erro e tentar entender qual objeto está nulo. Pode ser o objeto `con`. Da uma olhada e comenta aqui novamente.

Comment: Ele mesmo @AndrewRibeiro, rodei em modo debug e identifiquei que é con

Comment: Você apenas copiou e colou meu código? Acabei de notar um pequeno deslize ali. Ao invés de `Connection = conexao.con;`, use `Connection con = conexao.con;`.
Identificar o por que seu objeto `con` dentro da classe ConexaoSQL está dando null está fora do escopo desta pergunta.
Você debugar e verificar por que o objeto `con` dentro da classe ConexaoSQL não está sendo inicializado corretamente.
Quando este objeto funcionar, o código vai funcionar.

Comment: @AndrewRibeiro sim, apenas copiei e colei. Vou verificar o que consigo fazer daqui para frente, muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um objeto do tipo Usuário e preencher ele com as informações que vem do `Scanner`, pode ser no próprio construtor da classe usuário mesmo ou pelos métodos `set` da classe. E depois criar um método para inserir no banco passando esse objeto como parâmetro do método.

**Ex:**

```
public void inserirUsuario(Usuario usuario){
 //código para inserir no banco, tem vários exemplo de insert na internet
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta não representa, de fato, uma solução pro problema apresentado.